# How to secure Elliptic Curve ElGamal encryption against known plaintext attacks?

Tags: elliptic-curves, elgamal-encryption, known-plaintext-attack

If I have an encoding function  $f(x)$ that maps a message $m$ to a point $P$ on a suitable Elliptic Curve $E$ . If I have the public key $Q$ of my recepient then I can encrypt the message as follows:

Choosing a random number $k < n -1 $ where $n$ is the order of the curve E .

Calculating $C = [k] G $ where $G$ is the generator point of the curve E

Calculating $R = [k]Q $ where $Q$ is the recipient's public key

Now the message is encrypted by adding $P$ to $R$ to get 
        $C_e$ $( = R + P)$ which is sent along with $C$ to the recepient.

*DECRYPTION:*

Now for the recepient to decrypt my message they compute $R = [privatekey] C $ (where $C = [k]G $) and simply subtract $R$ from $C_e$ to get the encoded point $P$ back which is then decoded by an inverse function $f^{-1}(x)$ to recover $m$. 
**Now** , two problems arise : If the attacker *knows* the plaintext (suppose if I follow a particular format of data while sending messages ) he could encode his **guessed** plaintext and subtract it from $C_e$ to recover $ R $ back ! . If I used that same $ R  $ to encrypt further "blocks" of my message then the security of the later parts of my message has been breached!

*I realize that doing  something like a scalar multiplication over and over again for every block of data, would be a huge drawback in efficiency and speed.*

*Is there any way to compute a different $ R $ for every block of data, without using much resources and that too quickly ?*

*Does reusing the same $R$ for another message break security ?*

**NOTE: This question is for educational purposes only. It's for the sake of expanding my knowledge on Crypto.**

Comment: $R=[privatekey]C$ are you sure about this equality? $R = [k\cdot pivatekey]G$

Comment: @kelalaka Yes $ R = [privatekey] C $ where $ C = [k] G $

Comment: I noticed that the tag should be changed to known-plaintext-attacks, and I've also edited the title to further clarify my idea...

Comment: Well, you can of course random pad the message using e.g. OAEP, but the problem with EC is that there will be very little message space left - if any.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes♦Yes, but I use a probabilistic method to encode messages.

Comment: What you're describing is not ElGamal. ElGamal does not reuse randomness. As always, the correct solution to the original problem of encrypting long messages using something like ElGamal is [ECIES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme).

Comment: @Maeher ECIES is good and widely used, but is there a way around this using ElGamal? Is there a way to get a different $R$ for every block ?

Comment: @VivekanandV ElGamal does not operate on "blocks". The message space of ElGamal defined over group $\mathbb{G}$ is $\mathbb{G}$. You are encrypting several distinct messages. To do so, by definition, ElGamal uses independently uniformly distributed random values. Reusing randomness makes the scheme completely insecure.

Comment: @Maeher I encode the message into points on Elliptic Curve. Can you please illustrate how ElGamal in the case of Elliptic curves becomes insecure. In the traditional ElGamal if we reuse randomness, we are in big trouble, but how does it affect Elliptic Curve ElGamal ?

Comment: There is no conceptual difference between ElGamal using finite field arithmatic and ElGamal over elliptic curves. The only difference is the group it operates over. Having two ciphertexts for (encoded) messages $M$ and $M'$ using the same $k$ leaks $M-M'$, which trivially breaks security.

Comment: @Maeher Can you please tell me how the difference in encoded points breaks security ?

Comment: It allows you to check if two particular messages were encrypted, which immediately breaks any kind of indistinguishability based notion of security.

Comment: @Maeher I think as Maarten Bodewes♦  pointed out ciphertexts can be made indistinguishable by using randomized padding. But even if that's the case, given such a padding has not been applied, can an adversary decrypt the encryption if he knows nothing about the plaintext ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to compute a different $R$ for every block of data, without using much resources and that too quickly ?

There's no common way. Standard practice is [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_encryption) per [ECIES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme).

In a nutshell, ECIES is the same as EC-ElGamal with regard to $E$, $G$, $\text{privatekey}$, $Q$, $k$, $C$, $R$, but the shared secret $R$ is used (after a key derivation step) as the key to a symmetric authenticated cipher that conveys the message $m$. This removes the burden of mapping $m$ to a point on the curve, which severely limits the size of $m$, and typically is iterative thus has the potential to leak information about $m$ by side channels.

> Does reusing the same $R$ for another message break security (in EC-ElGamal)?

Yes. Assume $m_0$ and $m_1$ mapped to $P_0$ and $P_1$ are encrypted with the same $R$, into $C_0$ and $C_1$. It holds $C_0=R+P_0$ and $C_1=R+P_1$, therefore $P_1=P_0-C_0+C_1$. Thus $m_1$ can be found from $m_0$ and ciphertext. With $R$ fixed, the cipher is insecure under known-plaintext attack.

Additions per [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/172631):

- Even if the attacker has no knowledge of a plaintext $m_0$, s/he does learn something about the plaintext. In particular she can tell if $m_0=m_1$, since that's equivalent to $C_0=C_1$. This qualifies as a break, since the objective of encryption is to prevent adversaries from learning anything about plaintext (except its length). As an example, this allows to distinguish between a routine `Have a quiet nightshift Joe` ($m_0=m_1$) from an exceptional `Launch missile to target A` ($m_0\ne m_1$).
- Doubling $R$ at each message would be extremely insecure. It would hold $P_j+P_j-P_{j+1}=C_j+C_j-C_{j+1}$, and that allows to decipher any message sent encrypted twice, as $P_j=P_{j+1}=C_j+C_j-C_{j+1}$.

Comment: If the attacker has no knowledge of plaintext, is there any other way to break this cipher ? To prevent a known plain text attack does doubling $R$ for every next message give this cipher any immunity against it?

Comment: Thankyou for your elaborate and easy to understand 
 answer,  I thought about all the vulnerabilities that you illustrated.  I think the only way to make this secure is to use a random "one time" $R$, and also an encoding function that adds unpredictability to the message based on some secret key. So considering drawbacks, ECIES would be much quicker, faster and secure.