# Does reusing the same $R$ in Elliptic Curve ElGamal breach its security?

Tags: elliptic-curves, elgamal-encryption

In Elliptic Curve ElGamal if I reuse the same randomness to get the same point $R$ for different messages, how can it breach its security ?
Can you please illustrate with an example?

[Please see my earlier question here for further details](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/77514/74634)

Thankyou everyone in advance!

Comment: become an NSA-operative

Comment: @super Can you please decrypt that? :)

Comment: I am not an NSA-operative. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WECeM.png

Comment: @super My question has nothing to do with NSA. I would love to make Crypto that would be immune to surveillance of government or attackers !